# Magento shows blank index management page

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, indexing

The index management page suddenly showing full blank page. I debugged the code and figured out that the problem is with that function `$this->getChildHtml('grid');` at line 78 located at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php
How to resolve this? 
Thank You

Comment: have check magento log

Comment: Thank you Amit for your response.I checked and it is not generating errors log.

Comment: please make sure loggin is turned on under `system > configuration > developer > log` and check Apache php logs for errors

Comment: Hi Sander, i have checked logs and it is not showing any error related to index management.

Comment: @umairayub have a look through http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 and see if you can find any more detailed information on the problem.